# Using Javassist to modify code in other packages?

Tags: package, javassist

Is there a way to write a javassist program in a package other than the src folder that can modify other classes (either in the src folder or subfolders of the src folder).  I have messed around with `cp.addPath("/usr/local/javalib");` and I cannot get that to work. I do not know if that is because I am not using it properly, or if that isn't even an appropriate approach to modifying java files in other packages.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this much more difficult than was needed. If I want to grab a class object in another package, say for example I wanted to modify a "foo.java" class in a "stuff" package. I simply use: `pool.get(stuff.foo);`

That's it, now I have the foo class in the classpool.